# Clickable image filters content

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I've tried so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <img src="https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/content/dist2/images/sdgwheelnumbers.png" usemap="#Map2">

    <map name="Map2" id="Map2">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="79,4,97,8,87,34,79,33" onclick="clickBox(1)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="9,0,11,1,9,3,8,3" onclick="clickBox(2)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="9,4,11,2,12,3,10,5" onclick="clickBox(3)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="10,5,13,4,13,6,10,6" onclick="clickBox(4)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="10,6,13,6,13,8,10,7" onclick="clickBox(5)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="10,8,13,8,12,10,10,8" onclick="clickBox(6)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="9,9,12,11,10,12,9,10," onclick="clickBox(7)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="7,10,8,10,10,12,8,13" onclick="clickBox(8)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="6,10,7,10,8,13,6,13" onclick="clickBox(9)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="5,10,6,10,5,13,3,12" onclick="clickBox(10)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="4,9,4,10,3,12,1,11" onclick="clickBox(11)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="3,8,3,9,1,10,0,8" onclick="clickBox(12)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="3,6,3,7,0,8,0,6" onclick="clickBox(13)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="3,5,3,6,0,6,0,4" onclick="clickBox(14)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="4,4,3,5,1,3,2,2" onclick="clickBox(15)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="2,1,4,0,5,3,4,3" onclick="clickBox(16)">
        <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="4,0,6,0,6,3,5,3" onclick="clickBox(17)">
    </map>

</body>
```

I'm able to get an image but can't make it do anything. How do I connect the image area links to the filters in the site I have created?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to some link inside `clickBox` function using `location` e.g.

```
function clickBox(num) {
  location = `mypage/${num}`;
}
```

```js
function clickBox(num) {
  console.log(num);
  setTimeout(x=> location = `mypage/${num}`, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <p>HTML Image</p>
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" usemap="#Map2">
 
 <map name="Map2" id="Map2">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="70,0,90,0,80,30,70,30" >
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="90,0,110,10,90,30,80,30" onclick="clickBox(2)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="90,40,110,20,120,30,100,50" onclick="clickBox(3)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="100,50,130,40,130,60,100,60" onclick="clickBox(4)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="100,60,130,60,130,80,100,70" onclick="clickBox(5)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="100,80,130,80,120,100,100,80" onclick="clickBox(6)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="90,90,120,110,100,120,90,100," onclick="clickBox(7)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="70,100,80,100,100,120,80,130" onclick="clickBox(8)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="60,100,70,100,80,130,60,130" onclick="clickBox(9)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="50,100,60,100,50,130,30,120" onclick="clickBox(10)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="40,90,40,100,30,120,10,110" onclick="clickBox(11)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="30,80,30,90,10,100,00,80" onclick="clickBox(12)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="30,60,30,70,00,80,00,60" onclick="clickBox(13)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="30,50,30,60,00,60,0,40" onclick="clickBox(14)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="40,40,30,50,10,30,20,20" onclick="clickBox(15)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="20,10,40,00,50,30,40,30" onclick="clickBox(16)">
  <area alt title href="#" shape="poly" coords="40,0,60,0,60,30,50,30" onclick="clickBox(17)">
 </map>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine using the onClick attribute. Your HTML looks perfectly fine. I believe you are missing some javascript.

Here's a quick little javascript implementation that will log the input parameter to the console:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  clickBox = function(num) {
     console.log(num);
  }
});
```

You need to either include a js file in the header of your html document, or you need to add a js script in your html. Either way, add the code above and your click events should log their respective input numbers.

Here is a jsfiddle that is working, though I don't have your exact image so I grabbed one off of google. The image I grabbed off of google is not the same size as yours so the coords won't match up, but you'll at least be able to click where you know the coords are and get your results:
https://jsfiddle.net/r3ndva7f/#&togetherjs=qJVOk5N1g9